# How to float images right in Android RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I want to display a text and next to the text a dynamic number of images that should be floated to the right side.

That is what I have:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/bus" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/tram" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that if `icon1` is not visible (I control on my Java code) icon2 is not displayed on the right side anymore. It overlayed `text1`, because the referenced `icon1` is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, either your layout above is incomplete (and if so you should post the full thing) or your ids are broken (you've laid out `icon2` to the left of `@+id/1` when it should be to the left of `@+id/icon1`.

Try setting `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` on `icon2` and correct the layout ids.